# Creating Quarters column with months columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook

So using python in Jupyter notebook, I have this data df with a column named as "Month"(more than 100,000 rows) having individual numbers upto 12. I want to create another column in that same data set named as "Quarters" so that it can display Quarters for those respective months.

I extracted month from "review_time" Column using ".dt.strftime('%m')"

I am sorry if the provided information was not enough. New to stack flow.

So I extracted month from column name :"date". I created a variable a and then added that variable a to the main table.

```
a = df['review_time'].dt.strftime('%m')

df.insert(2, "month",a, True)
```

this is the output for `month.info()` column

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
Int64Index: 965093 entries, 1 to 989508
Series name: month
Non-Null Count   Dtype 
--------------   ----- 
965093 non-null  object
dtypes: object(1)
memory usage: 14.7+ MB
```

Comment: Pls add sample of your data and expected input

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html)

Example with a generic `dataframe`:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Month': [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]})
df['Quarter'] = pd.cut(df['Month'], [0,3,6,9,12], labels = [1,2,3,4])
print(df)
```

This prints:

```
    Month Quarter
0       1       1
1       2       1
2       3       1
3       4       2
4       5       2
5       6       2
6       7       3
7       8       3
8       9       3
9      10       4
10     11       4
11     12       4
```

Comment: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

Getting this error. I extracted month from "Date" Column using ".dt.strftime('%m')"

Comment: Use `dt.month` instead so you can get an integer. But that information was better in your question so we don't try to debug your previous code. Another option is convert the column to `int64`. That is why gtomer also requested a sample of your data, for future questions always include some lines of your `dataset` and your code.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to calculate the quarter from the month number. `qtr = ( month -1 ) // 3 + 1`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
from datetime import datetime

# lo and hi used to generate random dates in 2022
lo = datetime( 2022,  1,  1 ).toordinal() 
hi = datetime( 2022, 12, 31 ).toordinal()

np.random.seed( 1234 )
dates = [ datetime.fromordinal( np.random.randint( lo, hi )) for _ in range( 20 )]

df = pd.DataFrame( { 'Date': dates } )

df['Qtr'] = ( df['Date'].dt.month - 1 ) // 3 + 1

print( df )
```

Result

```
         Date  Qtr
0  2022-10-31    4
1  2022-07-31    3
2  2022-10-22    4
3  2022-02-23    1
4  2022-07-24    3
5  2022-06-02    2
6  2022-05-24    2
7  2022-06-27    2
8  2022-10-07    4
9  2022-08-22    3
10 2022-06-04    2
11 2022-01-31    1
12 2022-06-21    2
13 2022-06-08    2
14 2022-08-25    3
15 2022-10-10    4
16 2022-05-01    2
17 2022-11-22    4
18 2022-12-03    4
19 2022-09-04    3
```